# Cannot access Localhost in android emulator

Tags: android, django, android-studio, localhost, android-volley

i have a django server but the app crash in the android emulator, why?

it is the code:

```
final TextView t = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    t.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            t.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post the logcat. You need to tell the exception that is thrown and not catched. And which statement causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is running on localhost and app on emulator, then you have to give the other IP as BaseUrl in app.

steps:
-> Open terminal, and type ifconfig(on mac os)
-> Copy the inet IP address which is shown in en0, and set that as BaseUrl in the app

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate [How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator?lq=1)

In case `Genymotion` then try 10.0.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Use your computers actual IP address! replace 10.0.2.2 with your systems actual IP,check [java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.2 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954067/java-net-connectexception-failed-to-connect-to-10-0-0-2-port-80-connect-fai/32955942#32955942)